# Does Sitecore XM Cloud support user membership or other complex logic implementation?

Tags: user-management, xm-cloud

It is known that `XM cloud` is based on a SaaS cloud platform. We are wondering if it supports user membership or similar functions.

If `user membership` is supported, could you please explain how it works and provide some tutorials or documentation?

If user membership is not currently supported, will it be a future release? Or would we need to integrate other products to achieve this functionality?

Please let me know if this captures your question properly. I'm happy to clarify or rephrase further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XM Cloud support user membership, To create a user in XM Cloud, you must invite them to your `Sitecore Cloud Portal` organization and give them access to your `XM Cloud app`. When the team member logs in to the XM Cloud app, their user account is created in that XM Cloud app.

A team member must accept the invitation and log in to the XM Cloud app before an administrator can configure their access rights and security roles.

In the Sitecore Cloud Portal, you can assign the following app roles:

1. **User** - The XM Cloud user account has a content author role by default. You can assign security roles and access rights to their account.
2. **Admin** - A team member with an Admin role in the portal always has an administrator role in the XM Cloud app.

For more details refer below links.

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/creating-users-in-xm-cloud.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/portal/en/developers/sitecore-cloud-portal/invite-team-members-to-your-sitecore-cloud-portal-organization.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/add-a-user-to-a-role.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I would like to understand is whether public users can register through the front-end website, and if we can implement and extend front-end user membership capabilities. Specifically, can we set up standalone account registration, login, and membership center pages with logic using XM Cloud tech stacks?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of predefined users that XM Cloud provides. You can check in the article.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/the-user-accounts.html

And I hope you are looking for these kind of users.

- extranet\anonymous — a user who is viewing the free to access parts of a website.
- default\anonymous — a user who is assigned to an unauthenticated visitor who is viewing a website that does not have an assigned domain.

Hope this will give you some context.

Comment: thanks for the info provided. it's indeed helpful.